# Question related to stripe connect, card tokenization process and customer generate process

Tags: stripe-payments

Before you ask for some code, understand that this question is about the implementation technique than code mongering.

OK, so in order to save a customer in stripe connect to charge them later or monthly, here is the prescribed process:

step 1. Use Stripe.js to get card details of the user such as card numbr, exp date, cvv etc. which will be sent to stripe.

step 2. Stripe returns a token corresponding to the card like: tok_xyz, now this token can be used to generate a customer in Stripe and you will get customer id.

step 3. Once you have customer id, you can charge them anytime.

Now I have two questions:

1. If I provide same card details in the step 1 above, will strip return same token everytime? I am asking it so that I may know how to handle the condition when a user enters same card details twice and I don't accidentally create multiple entries in the database for same card again and again.
2. It's documented in Stripe that after they issue card token (step 1 above) the CVV remains valid only for few minutes and if you don't make a charge in that time, later on the card will become invalid so do I need to charge the customer right away with a small amount like 0.01$ or something? or when I create customer (step 2 above), stripe takes care of that?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you will get a different token and `tok_xxx` ID value every time. However, there is a [fingerprint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/object#card_object-fingerprint) property you can read from the token and compare to cards saved to the customer, to check for duplicates. There are some good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686415/stripe-check-for-existing-card) on StackOverflow showing examples of that.
2. True, the CVC value is only held for a short amount of time. If you make a charge during that time, it can be checked by the bank. Creating a charge outside that time doesn't make the card invalid, but it will likely lead to more chance of a decline. Luckily this isn't an issue — when you create a customer object Stripe performs a $0 authorisation charge(as described in the blue box [here](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards#saving-credit-card-details-for-later)). So as long as you either charge the token directly, or use it to create a customer object, as soon as you get it, you don't need to think about this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Upvoted and accepted, I wish I could give you more reputation but I can't...thanks again..really good one, solved my issues.

Comment: Hey, I had one more question related to stripe, posted just now, maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717924/stripe-connect-express-account

Comment: thanks again for the help, I had one more question related to stripe, maybe you could have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773128/in-stripe-connect-is-there-any-way-to-schedule-a-transfer-to-happen-when-the-ch