# Stripe is charging only 1% of the amount - test mode

Tags: stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe connect to charge a customer and then transfer commission to another associated account but I am stuck at the first step.

I have successfully taken card details of the customer and using stripe.js, I have tokenized it and then exchanged that token for a customer id which I saved in my DB.

Now for charging I am using:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                "amount" => 774,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "customer" => $customerId,
                "transfer_group" => $uniqueTransferString
            ]);
```

Now that actually makes payment of $7.74 instead of $774.00 and I have no idea why. Of course I am using everything in test mode.

The card I used to create the customer at the first place was: 4242 4242 4242 4242

I have tried to give charge amount as: 1000, 774.00 etc but every time it only charges 1% of the given amount.

I have searched but couldn't find help anywhere as if why is this happening.

Please help. Any push in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work in cents? Maybe done to make all `amounts` and integer

Comment: It is expected that if you charge '774' you will be charging $7.74. `amount` should be a positive integer representing how much to charge (e.g. 100 cents to charge $1.00, 1000 to charge $10.00, etc ),https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe always work in a currencys lowest amount. So in dollars that would be cents.

That mean to charge f.ex 1$ you need to multiply it by 100. This gives you 100 which is the amount you pass to stripe.

In your case to charge 774$ you would need to pass 77400 in stripes amount field

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, however its the first time when I came across a payment platform which takes money in cents, others which I have worked with like authorize.net etc, they all take original amount in dollors..thanks for the help

Comment: thanks again for your help, I had one more question related to stripe, maybe you could have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773128/in-stripe-connect-is-there-any-way-to-schedule-a-transfer-to-happen-when-the-ch